# Android screen "watermarked"

Tags: android

How could be done such thing, like "watermark" on top of any other Activities on Android?

In detail: `I need to show some message on top of everything what is running on my device`. No matter if this is game, movie, app.

1. Is possible to achive something on Android? My phone is rooted.
2. Is possible to use some OpenGL features?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

At first, I am using here `FrameLayout`, that is transparent and you can see "watermarked" text on image.

At second, I am using `android:background="#99 000000"` on my button and you also can see it on the image. First 2 digits, as i know, named alpha channel and you can set them from 0 to ff; 0 is fully transparent, and ff is non-transparent, as usual.

I think you get the idea or may be you can draw your custom image on canvas, put on your framelayout and set 50% trasparent-background. And you have to do this 50% transparent layers onto all your layouts and so, all activities will have watermark.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:background="#99000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This might affect a developer's own app, but it will not work for arbitrary other apps.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. So, if it possible, we can create a virus that sets non-transparent background with, for example, porn pic. User cant see anything, only our picture. Sounds funny. So it seems impossible?

Comment: @m9_psy: Of course we might create a virus, but this is not question what we can do with this, but if we can do it at all?

Answer (score 0):

Use a master activity which have layout according to you. And then use this master activity in other activity by extending to child activity.
Its simple.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to run a base activity and over that some intended activity to perform the action you want.

Now, you can use the concept of sub-activities and activities in android to ensure this type of result.

Comment: Is this the same as in ICS is made some "top" output (Settings -> Developer options -> Show CPU usage)?